# How to use karma in node and return a Promise from Server.start when singleRun is true

Tags: node.js, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, karma-mocha

I'm trying to use node to create a tool that will run Jasmine via karma several times based on configuration info I send it.

I'm starting with calling karma once and I'm having trouble with the server `Promise` resolving without the tests having run even when I'm running with `singleRun: true`.

If I'm going to call Jasmine several times in what the end user sees as a "single" operation, I need to compile all the return values from the `function doneCallback(exitCode)` lines to see if any are non-0.

That is, when `singleRun: true` is used, I don't think there's a chance of setting up an event listener like [the docs demonstrate](http://karma-runner.github.io/6.4/dev/public-api.html#runner-events):

> ```
> runner.run({port: 9876}).on('progress', function(data) {
>   process.stdout.write(data)
> })
> ```

I'm not creating a runner and running it. I'm simply executing `server.start` and watching it run the tests in the config once, and I need to get the results of that. Instead, all the `Promise`s are returning when the config is read and the server starts. No `Promise`s are coming back to the calling context when the "implicit" runner is done during singleRun. It's fire and forget [about listening to events].

Here's a modified version of my code:

```
function startKarma(karmaConfig) {
    var karmaPromise = karma.config
        .parseConfig(
            null,
            karmaConfig,

            // http://karma-runner.github.io/6.3/dev/public-api.html
            { promiseConfig: true, throwErrors: true }
        )
        .then(
            (parsedKarmaConfig) => {
                // http://karma-runner.github.io/6.4/dev/public-api.html
                const server = new karma.Server(parsedKarmaConfig, function doneCallback(
                    exitCode
                ) {
                    console.log("Karma has exited with " + exitCode);    // <<<<<<< happens last. exitCode is defined.
                    return exitCode;
                });

                var serverPromise = server.start();
                return serverPromise.then(function (x) {
                    console.log("server promise", x); // <<<<<<<<<<<< happens first, x === undefined
                    return x;
                });
            },
            (rejectReason) => {
                console.log("Error", rejectReason);
                throw rejectReason;
            }
        );

    return karmaPromise;
}
```

And I kick off the code like this:

```
// leaving out config creation
startKarma(config).then(function (after) {
    console.log("after", after); // <<<<<<<<<<<< happens second, after === undefined
});
```

And here's my "base config", which has `files`, `preprocessors`, and `basePath` overridden elsewhere in the code.

```
var baseConfig = {
    files: [{ pattern: "**/*.js" }],
    preprocessors: {
        "**/!(*test).js": ["coverage"],
    },
    basePath: "./",

    frameworks: ["jasmine"],
    exclude: ["**/node_modules/**/"],
    reporters: ["coverage", "mocha"],
    coverageReporter: {
        reporters: [
            { type: "text-summary" },
            { type: "html", dir: "../coverage/" },
            { type: "text", dir: "coverage/", file: "coverage.txt" },
        ],
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: karma.config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ["Chrome"],
    singleRun: true,
    concurrency: Infinity,
};
```

The best way I can explain what I want to do is, "*I want to get a handle to the runner within the singleRun Server.start and return its results to the calling code via a `Promise`.*" Not sure where I'm supposed to access the "implicit" runner's results.

In other words, with `singleRun: true`, I'd expect the `Server.start` `Promise` to be returned only once the tests have been run, not as soon as the server is up and running. Since it doesn't, I'm wondering where I can hook into the runner that must be running.

Results:

```
START:
server promise undefined
after undefined
01 05 2023 16:27:56.094:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.4.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/
01 05 2023 16:27:56.097:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
01 05 2023 16:27:56.103:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
01 05 2023 16:27:56.916:INFO [Chrome 112.0.0.0 (Windows 10)]: Connected on socket fLZkvHywy1zV36iIAAAB with id 22356421
  these are not real tests
    add2 function in global scope
      √ should return a value that is 2 greater than that which was pushed in  
    add2broken function in global scope
      × should return a value that is 2 greater than that which was pushed in  
    double function in global scope
      √ should return a value double that pushed in
    square function in global scope
      √ should return a value that squares that which was pushed in

Finished in 0.018 secs / 0.002 secs @ 16:27:56 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

SUMMARY:
√ 3 tests completed
× 1 test failed

FAILED TESTS:
  these are not real tests
    add2broken function in global scope
      × should return a value that is 2 greater than that which was pushed in  
        Chrome 112.0.0.0 (Windows 10)
      Expected 27 to be 7.
          at <Jasmine>
          at UserContext.<anonymous> (fakeTests/testSubdir/add2.test.js:26:28) 
          at <Jasmine>


=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 76.47% ( 13/17 )
Branches     : 50% ( 8/16 )
Functions    : 80% ( 4/5 )
Lines        : 81.25% ( 13/16 )
================================================================================
```

---

To be clear, I think setting `singleRun: false` and handling the server lifecycle "manually" would allow me to do what I want, but I would like to KISS and hook into a `singleRun: true` version if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Right Thing to do, I believe, is to wrap all that logic into my own `Promise`. That is, karma does not provide event hooks for single runs. That approach (described in the original question) is wasted effort.

To roll your own `Promise` wrapper, [do this](https://github.com/ruffin--/khutzpa/blob/main/services/wrappedKarma.js) (the key being `return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) //...`):

```
function startKarma(karmaRunId, overrides) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        overrides = Object.assign(
            {},
            karmaConfigTools.overridesForMochaTestingRun,
            overrides
        );
        var karmaConfig = karmaConfigTools.createKarmaConfig(overrides);

        karma.config
            .parseConfig(
                null,
                karmaConfig,

                // In most cases, parseOptions.throwErrors = true should also be set.
                // This disables process exiting and allows errors to result in rejected promises.
                // http://karma-runner.github.io/6.3/dev/public-api.html
                { promiseConfig: true, throwErrors: true }
            )
            .then(
                (parsedKarmaConfig) => {
                    // fwiw
                    // http://karma-runner.github.io/6.4/dev/public-api.html
                    // I'm not sure why it names the callback function doneCallback.
                    const server = new karma.Server(
                        parsedKarmaConfig,
                        function doneCallback(exitCode) {
                            // 0 is success/no test failure.
                            // Anything else is bad. Usually 1 afaict.
                            utils.debugLog("Wrapped karma has exited with " + exitCode);
                            karmaRunResults[karmaRunId] = exitCode;

                            resolve(exitCode);
                        }
                    ).on("progress", function (data) {
                        process.stdout.write(data);
                    });

                    server.start().then(function (x) {
                        utils.debugLog("server started", x);
                    });
                },
                (rejectReason) => {
                    utils.debugLog("Error", rejectReason);
                    throw rejectReason;
                }
            );
    });
}
```

Now I can wait until I get to the section I wanted initially:

```
const server = new karma.Server(parsedKarmaConfig, function doneCallback(
    exitCode
) {
    console.log("Karma has exited with " + exitCode);    // <<<<<<< happens last. exitCode is defined.
    return exitCode;
});
```

and instead of listening for that via karma, the `Promise` I added, well, acts amazingly  like a `Promise`, allowing the caller to wait around until it gets the information it wanted. If I need to call a ton of singleRun test suites, I group the calls in an array and `Promise.all` them. Again, [typical `Promise` stuff](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

#### TL;DR

The bottom line is that karma does not appear to allow you to listen to events from single runs. You have to set up an open-ended-lived (!singleRun) karma runner if you want to listen via karma's handler with code like `runner.run({port: 9876}).on('progress', function(data) { // ...`

You can, however, set up your own async (`Promise`-based) management with "multiple singleRun" based logic to accomplish the same thing, as shown above.